LTSPICE : incorrect behavior of bulk cap
I wanted to simulate a bulk cap for a 24V 50Hz smoothing to check my calculations but something is wrong in SPICE and I can't figure what:

Blue is the cap current and it goes to 0 after the cap is charged.
If we zoom at beginning:

It is as if the cap never discharges.
I took a PN for it :

The result is the same if I enter only a cap value (perfect capacitor)..

Try to move the GND from the Vin (delete it) to bulk cap.

"It is as if the cap never discharges." -- It doesn't appear to discharge because the time-constant of the capacitor and the high resistance load is so large (470 seconds).  Try a much smaller load resistor.

The current through the capacitor is not zero, your plot is showing current in amps while the capacitor discharge current is microamps, so you don't have enough resolution to see it.
You don't need to move the ground in the simulation, but you need to make sure your measurements are referenced to the correct point. You can do this in LTspice by clicking to measure and dragging to the point you want as a reference, or you can use a voltage controlled voltage source (VCVS) to get a ground referenced voltage from two points. Alternatively you can add a plot trace manually and set it to show the difference between two nodes.
Here is your original circuit, I've redrawn it using the COM symbol for the rectifier, capacitor and resistor common connection, and added a VCVS to measure the voltage across the capacitor referenced to ground.

The average voltage is 22.688 V, and you can see that the magnitude of the capacitor discharge current is:
$$
  \frac{22.688V}{100k\Omega} = 226.88 \mu A
$$
When the capacitor is charging (the peaks) the polarity is positive, when discharging (in between the peaks) it's negative, so -226.88 µA.
So the discharge current is exactly what we would expect.

Gosh I feel so stupid, I needed to add GND to this side:


This shorts out the supply through D3.

Through D3 @ negative halfwave of V1 ;-).

This is not what the comment by @G36 implied.

This answer is a newbie mistake equaling to what happens when an earthed signal generator is used as supply and earthed oscilloscope is used to measure capacitor voltage. D4 is shorted out by ground wires.
